# Drag and Drop Images and capture image name and order

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a web form.

I have a group of about 20 images displayed on the page. I want the user to be able to drag five images into a holding area, and to be able to arrange their order.

On submit, I'd like the names of those images, and their order, to become part of the $_POST data.

I'd appreciate it if someone could point me to a working example of this functionality that I can reverse engineer, point me to an open source project that offers this functionality, or can provide the code to do this.

I am using PHP, with jquery and js

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If already using JQuery, go for JQuery UI.

They have actions called DRAGGABLE and DROPPABLE which you apply to divs. It's a very elegant, easy to use setup.

Examples:
Look to the right for more examples

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

As for posting, at submit time you can iterate through the DOM, find the images in the "holder div" and post that OR you can hook into the event that fires every time an item is 'dropped' and write that to a hidden or other form element what is in each box.